# Dynamically change src in Google docs embedded viewer

Tags: jquery, iframe, google-docs

```
<div class="left" style="float:left" id="document-viewer">
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.mysite.be/doc.ppt&amp;embedded=true" width="620" height="780" style="border: none;" id="document-preview"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have an embedded google docs viewer. Everything works fine, but now I want to change the iframe src when I click a certain link to display another document.

```
 $('.document-slider-item').click(
        function(event){
           var url = 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=';
           url += $(this).attr('href');
           url += '&amp;embedded=true';
           event.preventDefault();
           $('#document-preview').attr('src',url);  
        });
```

This gives me `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I solved it, instead of changing the source, I load a new IFrame:

```
 $('.document-slider-item').click(
    function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var url = 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=';
       url += $(this).attr('href');
       url += '&amp;embedded=true';
       var iframe = '<iframe src="'+url+'" width="620" height="780" style="border: none;" id="document-preview"></iframe>';
       $('#document-viewer').html(iframe);
    });
```